# How to fix WinError 10048?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the working code in Ubuntu, but I need to rerun it in windows.

I tried the usual

```
response = requests.post(url_get, headers=headers, json=data)
```

and

```
with requests.post(url_get, headers=headers, json=data, stream=True) as r:
                response = r
```

and with `http.client`

```
http.client.HTTPSConnection(url)
```

and the same with timeout

```
http.client.HTTPSConnection(url,timeout = 10)
```

But again and again, I see OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

How to fix it without `sleep`,`timeout` and a lot of retrying of `get`?

Actually, I write it with

```
session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=8, backoff_factor=2)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('https://', adapter)
```

but I don't believe that coding under windows is so terrible, most likely I just don't know how)

Comment: Are there any places in this program where it listens on a port, as a server?

Comment: @NickODell i use just requests.get and post

Answer (score -1):

WinError 10048 indicates that the port is already in use by another application. You can try the following:

1. Check if the port is being used: Use the command prompt to check
   which program is using the port. You can use the command "netstat
   -aon" to see a list of open ports and their associated process IDs (PID). Then, use the task manager to identify the program that is
   using the port.
2. Restart the application: If you identify the program that is using
   the port, try restarting it to release the port.
3. Change the port number: If you can't stop the program using the
   port, you can try changing the port number to a different one that
   is not in use. Modify the application's configuration file or
   settings to use a different port.
4. Disable any firewalls or antivirus software temporarily: Sometimes,
   the firewall or antivirus software can block the port, preventing
   the application from using it. Disable these temporarily and try
   running the application again.
5. Reinstall the network driver: If none of the above solutions work,
   try reinstalling the network driver to reset the network settings.

Hopefully, one of these will help.